# Reflect on functions declared in a Groovy script

Tags: java, reflection, groovy

Is there a way to obtain reflection data on functions declared in a Groovy script that has been evaluated via a `GroovyShell` object? Specifically, I want to enumerate the functions in a script and access annotations attached to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimenting, I found this to be the easiest way:

```
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell();
Script script = (Script)shell.parse(new FileReader("x.groovy"));
Method[] methods = script.getClass().getMethods();
```

The `method` array has all of the functions defined in the script and I can get the annotations from them.

Answer (score 2):

Put **this** to the last line of Groovy script - it will serve as a return value from the script, a-la:

```
 // x.groovy
 def foo(){}
 def bar(){}
 this
```

Then, from Java code you can do the following:

```
 GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell();
 Script script = (Script) shell.evaluate(new File("x.groovy"));
```

Now it seems that there's no option to introspect the annotations of Groovy script from Java directly. However, you can implement a method within the same Groovy script and call that one from Java code, for instance:

```
//groovy
def test(String m){
  method = x.getMethod(m, [] as Class[])
  assert method.isAnnotationPresent(X)
}

//java
script.getMetaClass().invokeMethod(script, "test", "foo");
```